# What does it mean by "to be doing API development going forward" in the following?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-structure

I grab the below paragraph from a book learning C# Programming language:

> **Install Postman**

> This is optional, and up to you if you want to install – but I highly
> recommend it. I’ll be  using it at various points throughout the book,
> and given that it’s both free and excellent,  I don’t see why you
> wouldn’t. If you’re going **to be doing API development going forward**,
> then it’s essentially mandatory. It’s available as both a browser
> plugin or as a  stand-alone client. For more details on how to install
> and download, go over to  [www.getpostman.com/downloads/](http://www.getpostman.com/downloads/), and take a
> look.

First, I didn't realized what it means when it says "to be doing API development going  forward".
Also I wanted to know if there is any pattern as: "to do something going forward" (according to the bold part above), and if there is, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Going forward](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forward?q=going+forward#cald4-1-3-2)" just means "in the future". By contrast, "[going to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work)" is in the usual sense of indicating the future tense.

So "If you're going to be doing API development in the future…".

(That is, "If you will be developing APIs in the future…".)

---

By the way, I certainly don't consider Postman to be mandatory for API development. I manage fine with `curl`.

Comment: "Going to" is not a tense btw. It is a special structure that we use to talk about the future

Comment: Indeed; that's why I said it was indicating the future tense, rather than that it was the future tense.

Comment: So, could we say that "to do something going forward" is a kind of structure to state something is supposed to be done/taken place in the future?

Comment: Yes; more specifically, it indicates a *continuous* or *repeated* future action.